# Limit of a function at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R}$ be the function given by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \dfrac{x_1^2x_2}{x_1^4+x_2^2}&x\neq0 
                     \\  0 &x=0
       \end{cases}$$
(a) Prove that for each $x\in \mathbb{R^2}$, $f(tx)$ is a continuous function of $t\in\mathbb{R}.$
(b) Prove that $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

---

I am able to show the part (a) which is is rather uniformly continuous on $t$.
For part (b), I can simply move to polar coordinate maybe to show that the function is not continuous, I tried evaluating limit on polar coordinate which comes out to be $0$ only. I am unable show that the part (b) is discontinuous. Is there any use of part (a) in part (b), specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be worth discussing how to approach part (b) via polar coordinates.

Letting $x_1=r\cos\theta$ and $x_2=r\sin\theta$, the expression simplifies to

$$r\cos^2\theta\sin\theta\over r^2\cos^4\theta+\sin^2\theta$$

Now if you *fix* the angle $\theta$, then the limit as $r\to0$ will be $0$; this is, in effect, what part (a) of the question is all about.  But the point is, $\theta$ does not need to be fixed. For each value of $r$ you can pick a different angle. In particular, for $r\le1$ there is an angle $\theta_r$ such that $\sin\theta_r=r$. For this choice we find that

$${r\cos^2\theta_r\sin\theta_r\over r^2\cos^4\theta_r+\sin^2\theta_r}={r(1-r^2)r\over r^2(1-r^2)^2+r^2}={1-r^2\over(1-r^2)^2+1}\to{1-0^2\over(1-0^2)^2+1}={1\over2}$$

That by itself is enough to show the the limit for the original function does not exist (because it can't be both $0$ and $1/2$).  If you want to get fancy, you can choose the angle so that $\sin\theta_r=kr$ for any constant $k$ (for $r$ sufficiently small, i.e., $r\le1/|k|$). In that case you wind up with

$${(1-k^2r^2)k\over(1-k^2r^2)^2+k^2}\to{k\over1+k^2}$$

which can be any number between $-1/2$ and $1/2$.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Note that

- for $x_1=0 \implies \dfrac{x_1^2x_2}{x_1^4+x_2^2}=0$

but

- for $x_1=t$ and $x_2=t^2 \implies \dfrac{x_1^2x_2}{x_1^4+x_2^2}=\dfrac{t^4}{t^4+t^4}=\frac12$

Comment: Is there any possible use of part (a) in part (b) specifically? Rest is okay.

Comment: @Mann The two parts don't seem connected to me, for part $(b)$ $t$ is just a parameter for the trajectory $x_2=x_1^2$ which leads to a constant value also for $(x_1,x_2)\to (0,0)$. You can await for some other advice on that.

Comment: @Mann, the short as is, No. The longer answer is, Part (a) shows that when approaching the origin along any *straight line* the limit is $0$, so to show that the limit actually does not exist, you need to approach the origin along some sort of curve.